# Unable to install JDK-7u3-windows-x64

Tags: eclipse, java

I am unable to install JDK on my laptop (a 64 bit machine with Windows 7 Home Basic). Whenever I try to install JDK on it a screen flashes for permission and after that, there is no processing for installation.

I want to install eclipse and android sdk for android development.

Answer (score 1):

right click the **jdk or eclipse** and choose the `Run as administrator` mode. it will install your application.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar experience on Win7 Professional (64bit) with jdk-7u21-windows-x64

Turning off Windows's User Account Control fixed it (just remember to turn it back on when you're done)